# Tomboy creates a 0 folder in home directory

Tags: configuration, tomboy

Tomboy has created a directory called 0 in my home directory. It looks ugly wherever my home folder appears (screenlets). Is there someplace else I could move it. I've tried looking in `~/config/tomboy/` but could not find something useful.

The `0` directory consists of 3 folders - `0,1,2` each containing a `manifest.xml` file and some .note files.

Comment: I am in agreement with the answer MichaelMS gave, I sync my Tomboy notes with Ubuntu One and it's perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you turned on Tomboy's note synchronization feature, but didn't change the default synchronization folder (which is set to your home folder by default).

To fix this, go to Edit > Preferences in Tomboy, then go to the Synchronization tab, and uncheck the box next to "Automatically Sync in Background..." or choose the "Clear" button at the bottom.  The 0 folder in your home folder should be a duplicate (synchronized copy) of the actual notes folder, so it should be safe to delete.  If you want to be safe, you can try renaming it first, and see if your notes still show up in Tomboy.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. It seems I had tried to setup sync locally some time ago, and the location was not inaccessible, so Tomboy decided to sync to the default location, the home folder.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue.. if I could say that ... it still creates directory 0 and a manifest.xml. How can I avoid creating directories.